# Is it possible to change Vue.js application's metadata like title based on the view I'm currently on?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Right now, the title of my Vue.js application is always the same - the name of the application. I'm trying to achieve having a different title based on the view I'm currently on. For example:

**On this route:**

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
}
```

I want the title to be `Home`

**But on this route:**

```
{
    path: '/product/:id',
    name: 'specificProduct',
    component: SpecificProduct
}
```

I want the title to be the name of the product with that `ID`, which means that first I'd need to make a `GET` request from inside the component to get the name of the product based on its `ID` and then set the title page.

I checked the entire documentation of Vue.js and didn't see a chapter that handles something like that so I'm not sure how to do it myself. I saw some implementation by googling, but they were mostly hard coding the values so they won't work for my second scenario.

Comment: `document.title = 'New title'`?

Comment: @Anatoly I was wondering if there was a more Vue-ish way of doing this but this works too. Thanks!